# Как правильно проверять что Auto-renewable subscriptions еще не отменены и действительны?

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchases

Интересует правильный способ проверки таких подписок.

Answer (score 0):

Итак я разобрался в вопросе. Проверка делается запросом на сервер эпла с чеком (reciept) устройства. В ответе приходит много полезной информации в том числе покупки которые совершались и когда именно они совершались (целая простыня) по этим данным можно вычислить когда именно происходила последняя покупка и проверить не протухла ли она. Но правильно делать такую проверку на своем сервере. Т.е. получается что устройство делает покупку, затем отправляет запрос с чеком на наш сервер, а наш сервер делает запрос в эпл, затем возвращает результат в приложение.